# How can I get away from "mount point busy" after using semanage?

Tags: mount, selinux

I'm trying to label a port for SELinux (RHEL 8.8) using semanage:

> semanage port -a -t mylabel_port_t -p tcp 2345

This seems to work fine. But after running this command, it is impossible to remount the disk system as read-only:

> mount -o remount,ro /
>
> mount: /: mount point is busy

The mount point stays busy for hours after running this. If I do not run the semanage command, remounting works fine. Remounting after the semanage port labeling worked in RHEL 7.
How can I fix this? Is there an open file I can close manually, or in some other way make the mount point not busy. I know I can reboot, but would like to solve it in another way if possible.

Comment: What is actually surprising is that you could remount / read-only prior to calling `semanage`. Unless carefully partitioned, it is expected that a running system has several files on its root partition that are open for writing (this prevents the remounting RO). You can use `lsof -w +D /` and look for REGular files whose FD is a number directly followed by "w" or "u"

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I couldn't find any such files.